Unable to use closures (actions, funcs) in .NET debugger
I'm trying to debug a .NET 8 / C# project using Rider 2023.3 and I've run into a snag I've seen many times before. Using the interactive debugging prompt, whenever I try to evaluate an expression containing a closure (Func<whatever> or Action<whatever>,) I get the following error:

Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: length

Minimum code example:
> ((Func<int>)(() => 1))()
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: length

This means virtually all LINQ expressions are right out, and makes things highly inconvenient.
What is the reason for this error, and how do I fix it?

But LINQ expressions are not Func/Action, they are Expression<Func<..>>

what version of csi appears on the header prompt?

Report a problem

@Renat: LINQ-to-objects (IEnumerable<T>) has Func<T>. LINQ-to-specific data source (IQueryable<T>), mostly databases, has Expression<Func<T>>. A Func<T> lambda expression is still a C# expression.

@HansPassant OP mentioned they are using Rider
